# Eclipse RCP: Disable Menu Entry for Command via Plugin XML

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I know I can disable menu entries for commands in the plugin XML like that:

```
<visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
    <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
        <equals value="myperspective"/>
    </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

My question is: is there a way to just *disable* a menu entry, instead of hiding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is controlled by the handler for the command. The handler can define when it is active with `<activeWhen>` element and when it is enabled with `<enabledWhen>`

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="..."
        commandId="...">
     <activeWhen>
        .... 
     </activeWhen>
     <enabledWhen>
        ....
     </enabledWhen>
  </handler>
```

The menu item will be disabled if there is no active handler or the active handler is not enabled.

Comment: Can I disable eclipse rename command "org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename" ?